# Proving a function$f:\mathbb{R}^n\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ is onto.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

**Question:** Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^n$ be a continuously differentiable function satisfying $||f(x)-f(y)||\geq||x-y||$ for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^n$. Show that $f$ is onto.

**1.** I know that, a function $f:\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuously differentiable if $f'$ exists and continuous on $\mathbb{R}$. But what is the definition of continuously differentiable function on $\mathbb{R}^n$?

**2.** Next, how to prove $f$ is onto under that assumption in the question?

Thank you.

Comment: Continuously differentiable means the same thing on $\mathbb R^n$: that $Df$ exists and is continuous.

Comment: But what do you mean by $D(f)$ is continuous? Because  $D(f)$ is a linear operator on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Is this mean that the operator is continuous?

Comment: $D(f):\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is again a function, so it can be said to be continuous.

Comment: You can think about it in terms of partial derivatives too: that the partial derivatives of the component functions all exist and are continuous.

Comment: $D$ is the linear operator, but once it gets applied to $f$, it yields another function (the derivative of $f$)

Comment: oh please! $Df$ is a map from $\mathbb{R}^n$ into the linear maps from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$. Saying that $f$ is continuously differentiable means that this map is continuous.

Comment: Sorry, I made the mistake. Thomas is correct.

Comment: Ok, $D(f):\mathbb{R}^n\longrightarrow L(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is continuous. Now what is the topology on $L(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

Comment: @AVISEKSHARMA The topology induced by the operator norm $\|A\|=\sup_{\|x\|\leq 1}\|Ax\|$.

Comment: @AVISEKSHARMA the topology on $L(\Bbb{R}^n)$ is the "standard one" in the following sense: sure, you can consider the operator norm as described above, but it is also a classic theorem regarding equivalence of norms that every norm on a finite-dimensional vector space induces the same topology. So, for example, if you wish, you can take your favourite norm on $\Bbb{R}^{n^2}$, take a linear bijection $T: L(\Bbb{R}^n) \to \Bbb{R}^{n^2}$, and use this bijection to define a norm on $L(\Bbb{R}^n)$. This norm will then also induce the very same topology as the operator norm.

Comment: so the point is that if you want to prove something regarding continuity, just choose the most convenient norm for the question at hand (typically it will be the operator norm, but sometimes, other norms are easier to work with). And at the end, you'll arrive at the same result (though your intermediate steps may be different).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given distinct points $x_1,x_2\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $\|f(x_1)-f(x_2)\|\geq\|x_1-x_2\|>0$ implies that $f(x_1)\neq f(x_2)$. Hence $f$ is injective. By the invariance of domain theorem, the image $U$ of $f$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Let $y$ be a limit point of $U$ and $(y_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence in $U$ converging to $y$. Then $(y_k)$ is a Cauchy sequence. Put $x_k=f^{-1}(y_k)$ for each $k$. Since $\|x_k-x_m\|\leq\|y_k-y_m\|$ for all $k,m\in\mathbb{N}$, the sequence $(x_k)_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$ is Cauchy, hence has a limit $x$. By continuity of $f$, we have
\begin{align}
f(x)=\lim_{k\to\infty}f(x_k)=\lim_{k\to\infty}y_k=y\,.
\end{align}
Hence $y\in U$. This proves $U$ to be closed. The only subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ both open and closed are the empty set and $\mathbb{R}^n$ itself. The set $U$ cannot be empty, so it has to be $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Note that $f$ is not required to be continuously differentiable here, only continuous. Perhaps it's because the invariance of domain theorem is not assumed, and instead we have, for example, the inverse function theorem.

Comment: For those who saw it, my previous edit contained a mistake. It proved $f$ to be an open mapping onto its range, not into $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: How can we use the inverse function theorem? We don't know the derivative to be invertible?

Comment: @PankajTiwari I don't know how. Still trying to figure it out. But it may well be that we can't.